A homogeneous polynomial divides a polynomial if and if it divides each homogeneous component?
Let $k$ be a field (infinite, if necessary) and $f \in k[x_1, .., x_n]$ be a polynomial and $G\in k[x_1, .., x_n]$ a homogeneous polynomial. Let
$$
f = f_d + .. + f_0
$$
with $f_i$ homogeneous of degree $i$ or $0$. Is it the case that $G|f$ if and only if $G|f_i$ for all $i$?
I was only able to find something similar on the website: A polynomial vanishes if and only if each homogeneous component vanishes
Any clarification is appreciated!

That‘s correct. First suppose that for all i $G|f_i$, then clearly $G|f$. On the other hand if $G|f$ let $f = G * h$ with $h = h_d + .. + h_0$ with homogenous terms $h_i$. Then $f = G*h_d + .. + G*h_0$, where each of the terms $G*h_i$ is clearly homogenous of different degree and so necessarily $f_i=G*h_i$.

Because you can collect all terms of the same degree in one $h_i$ and $deg(f_i )= deg(G) + deg(h_i)$. $k[x_1, … ,x_n]$ has no zero divisors regardless of the characteristic of the underlying field k, so $f_i = 0 \iff h_i = 0$.
